# jpeg() function incompatible with paste() function in R?

Tags: r, jpeg, paste

I want to write jpeg files with dynamical filenames.
In `plot_filename` I concatenate strings with values from other variables to create
a dynamical filename.

```
plot_filename = paste("Series T_all","/",Participant[i],"/",Part[i,2],"/",Part[i,3],".jpg")
```

The output of plot_filename is just another string: `"Series T_all / 802 / 1 / 64 .jpg"`

However when I want to use this string as a filename in the `jpeg()` function

```
jpeg(filename= plot_filename, width = 2000, height = 1500, quality = 100, 
     pointsize = 50) 
plot(T1)
dev.off()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in jpeg(filename = paste("Series T_all", "/", Participant[i], "/",  : 
  unable to start jpeg() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In jpeg(filename = paste("Series T_all", "/", Participant[i], "/",  :
  unable to open file 'Series T_all / 802 / 1 / 64 .jpg' for writing
2: In jpeg(filename = paste("Series T_all", "/", Participant[i], "/",  :
  opening device failed
```

But when I just use a plain string (without the paste function) as a filename

```
name="plot_filename.jpg"
```

the `jpeg()` function works just fine.

Does anybody know how this is possible? It seems to me that in both cases you're just inputting strings into the `jpeg()` function so I don't see why one but not the other would work.

Thanks

Comment: These functions are of course compatible. Do you actually have a folder named "Series T_all " and in this folder another one with the participant number and a space, etc. Change the "/" into something like "_".

Comment: Well, do the subdirectories you specify there exist? You also most likely want to use `paste0` instead of `paste` or `paste(..., sep="/")`.

Comment: As Roland is suggesting, your concatenation is clearly putting a lot of whitespace into the string, so the path is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
plot_filename = paste("Series T_all","/",Participant[i],"/",Part[i,2],"/",Part[i,3],".jpg")
```

separates the individual strings with spaces (the default) as you can see in your output example

```
"Series T_all / 802 / 1 / 64 .jpg"
```

This path, however, does not exists.
If you use

```
plot_filename = paste("Series T_all","/",Participant[i],"/",Part[i,2],"/",Part[i,3],".jpg", sep="")
```

this should give a string like

```
"Series T_all/802/1/64.jpg"
```

In general, sep= can take any character or string. So you can also use sep="/" to separate your strings so you do not have to write "/" when you concatenate you strings. However, this would affect the concatenation of Part[i,3] and ".jpg". If you want to use it that way, you may append ".jpeg" in a second step with sep="". For your case, I think it is okay just to use sep="".

Comment: Hey, clearing the whitespace in the path name indeed did the trick. What I stupid mistake... As you might have guessed, i'm new to programming in R :p Thanks a lot